# Purpose of enableVertexAttribArray, bindBuffer, and vertexAttribPointer in render function

Tags: javascript, webgl

Looking through this example at [learnwebgl.brown37.net](http://learnwebgl.brown37.net/rendering/render_example_03.html#the-model), I can't understand the purpose of lines 182-189 in simple_model_render_03.js, or lines 4-7 in the following snippet:

```js
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_Transform_location, false, transform);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles_vertex_buffer_id);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Vertex_location, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Vertex_location); // this
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles_color_buffer_id); // this
gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Color_location, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); // this
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Color_location); // and this
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, number_triangles * 3);
```

When I comment out these lines and click "Re-start", the output is exactly the same. If the output is the same, then what is the purpose of these lines?

Comment: These lines are the vertex specification. Very likely this is duplicate code, and these lines are in a different place in the code when the mesh is loaded. WebGL (and OpenGL) are state engines, all states are persistent. If you do not load another mesh these lines are superfluous, but they gain importance if you want to draw multiple meshes.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I looked through the source code and found no instances of `vertexAttribPointer` or `enableVertexAttribArray` outside the render function. Could the meshes be being loaded in some other way?

Comment: Actually, no. If you don't specify the vertex attributes, the code won't work. You missed something. Otherwise the behavior can not be explained.